# Function to get user ip address

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most accurate way to retrieve a user's correct IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php)

Is there any better function in php to get user ip address?
this is what i use at the moment

```
function GetIP()
{
if (getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP") && strcasecmp(getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP"), "unknown"))
$ip = getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
else if (getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR") && strcasecmp(getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"), "unknown"))
$ip = getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
else if (getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") && strcasecmp(getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"), "unknown"))
$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
else if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] && strcasecmp($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], "unknown"))
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
else
$ip = "unknown";
return($ip);
}
```

Comment: "Better" in what sense? In what way does the code you have need improvement?

Comment: Where did you get that function from? Why do you use it? What should be bad about it? Did you run into any problems?

Comment: @Jon - the indentation, for a start.  ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, your function should behave as expected, but here are some suggestions:

```php
// lowercase first letter of functions. It is more standard for PHP
function getIP() 
{
    // populate a local variable to avoid extra function calls.
    // NOTE: use of getenv is not as common as use of $_SERVER.
    //       because of this use of $_SERVER is recommended, but 
    //       for consistency, I'll use getenv below
    $tmp = getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
    // you DON'T want the HTTP_CLIENT_ID to equal unknown. That said, I don't
    // believe it ever will (same for all below)
    if ( $tmp && !strcasecmp( $tmp, "unknown"))
        return $tmp;
        
    $tmp = getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
    if( $tmp && !strcasecmp( $tmp, "unknown"))
        return $tmp;
        
    // no sense in testing SERVER after this. 
    // $_SERVER[ 'REMOTE_ADDR' ] == gentenv( 'REMOTE_ADDR' );
    $tmp = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    if($tmp && !strcasecmp($tmp, "unknown"))
        return $tmp;
        
    return("unknown");
}
```

Comment: forgot a ; after  return $tmp

Answer (score 45):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php/2031935#2031935):

```
function GetIP()
{
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true)
        {
            foreach (array_map('trim', explode(',', $_SERVER[$key])) as $ip)
            {
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE) !== false)
                {
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Checks for IPs (in order) in:

1. `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`
2. `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`
3. `HTTP_X_FORWARDED`
4. `HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP`
5. `HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR`
6. `HTTP_FORWARDED`
7. `REMOTE_ADDR`

Remember that the only IP address you can trust is the one coming from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Comment: Why does it check `REMOTE_ADDR` last then?

Comment: @Anther: For when the user isn't behind a proxy.

Comment: what is the return value's data type ?

Comment: Very good approach to get IP address but I've made some changes, I am working in development environment and my IP address is IP V6 ::1 (equal to 127.0.0.1).. It was not passed in this function.. So I added following lines right after foreach loop..     if ( isset( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) ) {
    return $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   }
   
   return '';