# definitive way to get user ip address php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Function to get user ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717926/function-to-get-user-ip-address)

```
<?PHP

$ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

echo "Your IP is $ipaddress!";

?>
```

I was told this way of getting ip address has issues such as being able to fool.  Is there a better way to gather ip address? looking for tutorials of better way to get ip address?

Comment: Nope, there isn't! Might be able to fool it, but I have never seen it in practice or read it's being done in the masses.

Comment: @genesis - but this question is messed up a little and not so clear. I think there is no need to use anything else than just $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] . There isn't anything better. The fooling of IP address would be done at IP level so there's no way you can solve/detect it in PHP.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the only reliable IP address you'll get - it's extracted directly from the TCP stack and is where the current connection was established from. This means if the user is connecting via a proxy, you'll get the proxy's address, not the user's.

Any of the other header-based ones are unreliable, as HTTP headers are trivial to forge. You can use the information from them, if you'd like, as long as you don't TRUST it.