# limiting login attempts of user

Tags: php

i need help for limiting login attempt of the user. this is my code.

```
$login = login($username, $password);
        if($login === false) {
            if(isset($_COOKIE['login'])){
                      if($_COOKIE['login'] < 3){
                           $attempts = $_COOKIE['login'] + 1;
                           setcookie('login', $attempts, time()+60*10); //set the cookie for 10 minutes with the number of attempts stored
                           $errors[] = 'That username/password combination is incorrect!';
                      } else{
                           echo 'You are banned for 10 minutes. Try again later';
                      }
            } else {
                   setcookie('login', 1, time()+60*10); //set the cookie for 10 minutes with the initial value of 1
             }

        } else {        
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
            header('Location: ../../home.php');
            exit();
        }
```

it looks right for me but it just wont work. the user could still access his/her account even after attempting 3 login.

Comment: Umm I'm not cookie expert but won't the user be able to circumvent this by deleting their cookie?

Comment: that's silly , clients can  write/flush cookies, do it in the database

Comment: so how will i do that in the database? i have no idea. please help :/

Comment: oh im just running this from the localhost so security doesnt matter for now

Comment: *"oh im just running this from the localhost so security doesnt matter for now"* **Famous last words.**

Comment: what? lol just please help me for now :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an SQL database, im currently working on a snippet of code, give me about an hour and ill throw an exampl up for you

---

PHP:

```
<?php
$host = "";//Host name
$username = "";//MYSQL username
$password = "";//MYSQL password
$db_name = "";//Database name
$tbl_name = "";//Name of login table
$bl_name2 = "";//Name of table to store IP if attempt is incorrect

//connect to server and select database
try{
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name.'',$username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);}
catch(PDOException $e){
echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();}

//get users ip next, as this is for a log in, this example will show for username and pass also
$userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$userPassword = $_POST['passwordfromform'];
$userUsername = $_POST['usernamefromform']

if(empty($userUsername) && empty($userPassword)){
die("You must enter a username and password");
}

//check for log in excess
$checkSql="
SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_name2."
WHERE PostersIP = '".$userIP."'
";
$stmt = $db->query($checkSql);
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
if($rowcount >= 7){//change this number to reflect the nuber of login chances
die("You have tried to log in too many times");
}

//check to log in
$insertSql = "
SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_name."
WHERE USERNAME = '".$userUsername."'
AND PASSWORD = '".$userPassword."'";

//execute check query
$result = $conn->query($insertSql);
if($result != false){
echo "Username and Password were correct!";//link to correct page
}
else{
$incorrectSql="
INSERT INTO ".$tbl_name2."
(PostersIP) VALUES 
('".$userIP."')";
    $result2 = $conn->query($incorrectSql);
     if($result2 != false){
          die("You entered an invalid username or password, your attempt has been stored.");
        }
die("Error inserting data");
}
?>
```

I did not test this live, so there may be a few flaws, however i commented it pretty well for ya. you do need a second table to store user submission ips. this is a VERY messy way to do this. Im very sure there are better ways to do it, but theres my 10 minute solution :)

Comment: @arukiri123 no problem, something else you should keep in mind, is the user has a dynamic ip or uses a proxy, it makes this method a little less useful

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection and will likely allow an attacker to take over the machine. Do not interpolate user-supplied strings ($userUsername, $userPassword) into an SQL statement. In PDO you must use https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score 1):

Use a database and I would suggest using IP address. check out this [definitive way to get user ip address php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794782/definitive-way-to-get-user-ip-address-php)

Capture the username, password and timestamp, record these to the table along whether failed or success. Set your parameters of when you want to ban them.

Add a check to you login script to check the IP address and only allow them to enter the details if that IP address hasn't been used for 3 failed attempts.

Obviously, you may need a new table for the banned IP address and the time when they are allowed to re-enter details.

Comment: There's a downside of using IP addresses though, and that is large networks: Schools, workplaces, hot spots etc.

Comment: @thordarson - true enough. depends on application. I guess you could record the username in the same way and verify if the password and check if login was successful. - Valid point none the less.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make another table that has cols: Username, Timestamp, Attempts.
This would check the username for attempts within 10 min of the timestamp (set on the first attempt).

```
If ( attempts > max attempts then attempt login )
   { "Sorry to many attempts"
   else { Check login 
       if failed { Attempts++ } else (login success) { set attempts = 0 } 
(reset attempts counter)}
 }
```