# Post Remote Address with CURL

Tags: php, jquery, curl

I've set up an ajax script with jQuery to have a user subscribe to a mailing list.

Is there a way I can send the subscriber's `REMOTE_ADDR` in curl? Right now it's posting the IP_ADDRESS as the address of the server, but I need to capture the subscriber's ip.

I'm not trying to spoof anything, I just need to find a way to make sure I'm getting accurate information for email marketing compliance.

I tried adding the following to the curl post:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$ipaddress = array(
    "REMOTE_ADDR: $ip",
    "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"
);          

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $ip_address);
```

but I'm still getting the server ip.

Comment: I don't think you can just change your IP address sent in the header like this. First, this would be a bit too easy to misuse. Second, the server would then not send the answer to your request back to you, but to the user's IP, or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of data from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is not real. for more information see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6794901/2855673

You must check all headers by php. Many open libraries do this. just search and get your fave code. like: https://gist.github.com/cballou/2201933

Comment: So how can I post information to a remote server with PHP and keep the user's IP intact?

Comment: Decided to use JSONP instead, thanks though, your answer was good.

Comment: Yea, you can get ip address with JSON. Use http://jsonip.appspot.com/ appspot for these. for example:

$.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?",
    function(data){
       alert( "Your ip: " + data.ip);
  });

This is for alert user IP. change these as yours.