# how to show ip address on the web?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find a user's IP address with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768/how-do-i-find-a-users-ip-address-with-php)
>   [How can I get the user's IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848091/how-can-i-get-the-users-ip-address-in-php)

I make application web based. I want to show the IP address of the user/visitor who visit my web. I've used the script to find the IP address but it didn't work and no IP show. How to solve it?? do I miss something? This is my php script :

```
function get_ip()
{
    global $ip;
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

$ip = get_ip();
```

Please, I really need your help ! Thank you ...

Comment: Add $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REAL_IP"]

Comment: Do a print_r( $_SERVER ); to see what you are playing with.

Comment: You don't need `global $ip;` btw

Comment: @Sergey, where I have to add that script??

Answer (score 5):

Your script does not display the result from the function call, only assigns it to the $ip variable.  You'd want to add the following to display its value:

```
echo 'IP Address: ' . $ip;
```

Cheers.

Comment: actually, just do echo get_ip(); at the end of your file.  You can get rid of $ip = get_ip() all together unless you need it somewhere else.  No use declaring a variable unless your going to use it in more than one place!

Comment: @alecwhardy - Good point.  Just thought I would put it this way so they could get some insight on how functions work and how variables and functions can interact.  :)

Comment: @alecwhardy: Another use of a variable is to give a value a name. Works even when used once and can make sense.

Comment: it works inside a function, globally its not a good idea to have any variables if you can keep everything inside a class as a property.