# How to find the ip address of the users, who login into my site,php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find a user's IP address with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768/how-do-i-find-a-users-ip-address-with-php)

How to find the ip address of the users, who login into my site,php

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I find a user's IP address with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768/how-do-i-find-a-users-ip-address-with-php).

Answer (score 0):

`$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Will return the IP address where the request came from. This may be the proxy IP address however.