# PHP - Get the public ip

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find a user's IP address with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768/how-do-i-find-a-users-ip-address-with-php)

I have a form in my PHP page. Users fills in his credentials and the message and presses send. I get his question through email and can answer him.

But I would also like to add the public IP of the person to the email, is this possible?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to fetch the user's IP address.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: On my local site i am getting 127.0.0.1. Can't I get my public ip on my local site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).  But it's not necessarily reliable.

Comment: I'm not aware of any method of spoofing REMOTE_ADDR short of forging IP packets.  However, it is worth nothign that REMOTE_ADDR may be the address of a proxy (even one you yourself set up) rather than the remote user.  E.g., I have nginx in front of apache, so the REMOTE_ADDR apache receives is that of my nginx server.

Comment: @Frank: That's roughly what I was hinting at!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but if you really want to make sure you are getting the right IP and not the proxy IP then i have found this function to be helpful

Note : i am not the owner of this code, i found it somewhere over the internet

```
function get_real_ip()
{

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"];
    }
    else
    {
        return $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah please make these snippets popular so it's really easy to spoof the mail-scripts.

Comment: All `$_SERVER["HTTP_*"]` vars are trivially spoofed.

Comment: Valid point but whats the real work around? Personally i store both `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` and any other forwarded for type var I can find.

Answer (score -4):

You can use the following code:

```
$ip = $REMOTE_ADDR;
```

Comment: You shouldn't be relying on register globals to be turned on.

Comment: I think that requires `register_globals`