# Get real IP behind Proxy behine Cloudflare?

Tags: php, proxy, ip, cloudflare

How do i get the Real IP of a visitor who is using a proxy if my server is using Cloudflare?

So far this works if a visitor open my server (which is using cloudflare) without using a proxy

```
isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"] : $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. PHP is only capable of reading the IP address purported by the browser.

Comment: It dosen't matter what CloudX you are using, if the client's proxy is not transparent you can't get his real IP address, otherwise you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285775/php-get-the-public-ip)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40377635/3599237

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR ?

You can see it in action here: http://canhazip.com/more.php  which is passing through CloudFlare. You can use that page if you'd like to test with a proxy as well.

p.s. Disclaimer: I work at CloudFlare.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can install mod_cloudflare for Apache.

https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads#mod_cloudflare
https://github.com/cloudflare/mod_cloudflare