# IP Address of the machine in PHP gives ::1 but why?

Tags: php, ip-address

I am trying to fetch the ip address of my machine through php. For that I am writing the code like:

```
<?php echo  "<br />".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>
```

But this piece of code is not working. It is returning "`::1`".
Please help me how to get the actual IP Address.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is not the IP address of your machine.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Identify server IP address with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800927/identify-server-ip-address-with-php) -- or if you need the other thing -- [How do I find a user's IP address with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55768/how-do-i-find-a-users-ip-address-with-php)

Comment: Of what machine? Your server that the PHP is running on? Your desktop that the browser connecting to the server is running on?

Comment: ::1 is an alias for localhost

Comment: `::1` is the actual IP. It is an ipv6 loopback address (i.e. localhost)

Comment: if you run that php script on the server itself of course it will return ::1 (i.e. localhost). Put the script on different server.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`::1` is the actual IP. It is an ipv6 loopback address (i.e. localhost). If you were using ipv4 it would be `127.0.0.1`.

If you want to get a different IP address, then you'll need to connect to the server through a different network interface.

Comment: Perfectly well explained!

Answer (score 14):

If you are trying to run localhost, this answer will fix your problem. Just few changes on

```
apache2/httpd.conf
```

search all "listen" words
ex:

```
Listen 80
```

Make like this.

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

than restart your apache

```
$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]
```

will show  `Listen 127.0.0.1`

you can see answer in this [detailed answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13649642/5818602)

Answer (score 8):

If you mean getting the user's IP address, you can do something like :

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else{
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
?>

<?php echo  "<br />".$ip;?>
```

It will get the user's actual IP address, regardless of proxies etc.

Comment: It's not answer on the question that was asked, but it's useful thing.

Comment: I assumed that's what the OP actually meant, but I might be wrong

Comment: I think he/she was just curious why `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returns `::1`. Maybe I am wrong. Whatever +1 from me.

Comment: This answer is very insecure, as anyone can set an "X-Forwarded-For" header and spoof another IP.

Answer (score 4):

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is the IP address of the client.

$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] is the IP address of the server.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer: You are using it on local server.
Try running

```
function getUserIpAddr(){
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
        //ip from share internet
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }elseif(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
        //ip pass from proxy
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }else{
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

echo 'User Real IP - '.getUserIpAddr();
```

in real server. Or you can also user online php executor.

Answer (score -2):

Look at the output of `phpinfo()`. If the address is not on that page, then the address is not available directly through PHP.

Comment: '$http_client_ip= $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        $http_x_forwarded_for=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        $remote_addr=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        if(!empty($http_client_ip))
        {$ip_address=$http_client_ip;}
        else if(!empty($http_x_forwarded_for))
        {$ip_address=$http_x_forwarded_for;}
        else
        {$ip_address=$remote_addr;}
        echo $ip_address;'

Comment: Why the sudden downvote? This answer shows that the information either **is** or **is not** available to PHP.