# not getting the ip address in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm getting the current date-time.but not getting the ip address....the output is ::1 ..why this is happening ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1KOd.png)

```
<?php 
  defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No Direct Script Access Allowed');

  class Ip_address extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index(){
      // var_dump($_SERVER);
      $this->load->helper('date');
      echo $date = "Current Time Is: ". date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      echo "<br/>"; 
      echo $this->input->ip_address();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Posiible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517371/ip-address-of-the-machine-in-php-gives-1-but-why

Comment: Thanks A Lot.I've seen some post which is telling me to check the base_url() wheather i've set it or not .But i've set that.which made me confused. Thanks A Lot For The Link

Comment: This function will not work if you are working on localhost. Try this code on a remote server.

Comment: Oww... I got it ..Thanks

Comment: Please mark the answer if helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

The IP ip of `::1` is identical to `127.0.0.1`. If you want see the address like `192.168.x.x` then you may try with another computer for example you set computer A as local server then you open the system on computer B (must be on the same network), you will see the different address printed.

You may try and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache is listening for IPv6 connections by default (::1 i.e. localhost). If you just want IPv4, try to disable IPv6 connections in your Apache configuration.

If you want to get a different IP address, then you'll need to connect to the server through a different network interface.