# Why the super global array element $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] is not returning proper value?

Tags: php, localhost, ip-address, superglobals, server-variables

As per my knowledge the super global array element `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` returns the IP address of the host server.

I've installed PHP using **XAMPP server software** on my machine that runs on **Windows 10** operating system.

I wrote following code in a file titled **demo.php**(Location of file on my drive is **C:\xampp\htdocs\php_playground\demo.php**)

The code in a file **demo.php** is as follows :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

  <?php 
    echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
  ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

and the output of above code I received after running the program in a web browser by hitting the URL `http://localhost/php_playground/demo.php` is as below :

```
::1
```

[image: See the attached screenshot]

I'm not understanding this output.

Also, as a part of guessing I run the same program by hitting the URL **http://127.0.0.1/php_playground/demo.php** in a web browser and I got the following output :

```
127.0.0.1
```

I want to know why there is a discrepancy in the output of the same program and why it's not returning proper value in first case?

Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IP Address of the machine in PHP gives ::1 but why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517371/ip-address-of-the-machine-in-php-gives-1-but-why) and even this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699454/should-a-mamp-return-1-as-ip-on-localhost

Comment: @Thamilan : My question is different than that question I'm asking for $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] and in that question $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is used which is now considered deprecated.

Comment: Wut, `REMOTE_ADDR` is deprecated?! – Anyway, what `SERVER_ADDR` gives you is the IP address of the interface the server received the request on. Since it's using the local loopback interface, that's what you see. What else did you expect?

Comment: @deceze : Nothing sir and Sorry for my mistake. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']  is not deprecated.